# What term means "the area beyond the surrounding area"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to find a word which is a good match for the word "surrounds" (n., the surrounding land or territory), but which instead describes all of much the space not included in the "surrounds".

To explain a bit more clearly, suppose "surrounds" approximately refers to the territory visible within the horizon in all directions. The word I am looking for likewise approximately refers to all of the land beyond that. Whether it refers to the entire rest of the globe or not is perhaps not important, but I am not looking for a strictly professional or scientific term, just one which might be a good pair with "surrounds", which to me, sounds a bit informal.

Comment: "Outlying areas" may be similar to what you need...

Comment: @RoryAlsop *outlying* is just another adjective to modify *area* and doesn't change the meaning to *beyond the surrounding area* it just changes meaning to something else – from OED: Situated at a distance from the centre of an area; remote, out-of-the-way

Answer (score 3):

`Outskirts` is the correct term I believe.

```
John lived in the outskirts of the city
```

`Outlaying areas` is also correct, but certainly less common and seems a little less conversational.

Answer (score 1):

I visualize a circle with a person at the center. The horizon represents a belt around the circumference. What's beyond that belt is what we're trying to name.

The previously suggested word "outlying" could work, but it doesn't **definitely** imply the space outside of that belt we're calling something like "the surroundings". If you're trying to maintain a level of certainty with this term, and you already have a sense and even a name for the inner territory and the surrounding territory, I would suggest some compound using "[extra-](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/extra?s=t)".

> "extra-"
>   a prefix meaning “outside,” “beyond,” freely used as an English formative.

Perhaps some form of *extra-* + *[adjective form of name for area inside the circle]*:

- Extra-territorial (if you're talking about an expanse of land)
- Extra-spacial (if you're talking about dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the observer, the areas may be called the *central* or *inner*, the *peripheral* and the *outlying* or *beyond*.

@Rory Alsop was correct in suggesting *outlying* areas.